# Printing certain elements from JSON python

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I've ran the following code using python to create a json structure and I'm trying to print a list for all of the "title" elements inside the 'foods' structure

```
import re
import json
from subprocess import check_output
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = re.search("__reactInitialState__ = (.*);", requests.get(url).text)[1]
data = json.loads(data)
```

I cant seem to access the foods structure in order to get the title elements to get the output. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output of title elements in json format.

```
import re
import json
import requests

url = "https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/avocado_pasta_with_peas_31700"
data = re.search("__reactInitialState__ = (.*);", requests.get(url).text)[1]
data = json.loads(data)
data=data["recipeReducer"]["recipe"]["stagesWithoutLinks"][0]['ingredients']

title=[]
for i in data:
    j=i['foods'][0]['title']
    title.append(j)
print(title)
```

Output:

```
['penne', 'avocado', 'garlic', 'coconut oil', 'salt', 'lemon', 'mint', 'peas', 'chilli']
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need *re* for this.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
(r := requests.get('https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/avocado_pasta_with_peas_31700')).raise_for_status()
soup = BS(r.text, 'lxml')
ingredients = [li.find('a').getText() for li in soup.select('li.recipe-ingredients__list-item')]
print(ingredients)
```

**Output:**

```
['penne', 'avocado', 'garlic', 'coconut oil', 'salt', 'lemon', 'mint', 'peas', 'chilli']
```